# Почему jira пытается скачать зависимости с разных источников

Tags: maven, jira, artifactory

У меня jira пытается скачать зависимости из сервера.
У меня есть репозиторий который настроен и прекрасно работает. Этот репозиторий дублирует данные с сервера (фактически является защищенным шлюзом ).

НО почему-то jira пытается подключиться напрямую к серверу, при этом он и к репозиторию обращается :3
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думал что в jira соединения с сетью и с интернетом настраивается в maven, но как понял это либо не совсем так, либо надо обязательно устанавливать в настройках (atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.2.14\apache-maven-3.2.1\conf\setting.xml ) прокси.

вот настройки mavena **setting.xml** лежащие в (atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.2.14\apache-maven-3.2.1\conf)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>maven-public</id>
          <url>http://n7701-sys274:8081/artifactory/maven-public</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
         <id>maven-external</id>
          <url>http://n7701-sys274:8081/artifactory/maven-external</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>maven2</id>
          <url>http://n7701-sys274:8081/artifactory/maven2/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>public</id>
          <url>http://n7701-sys274:8081/artifactory/public/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>public</id>
          <url>http://n7701-sys274:8081/artifactory/public/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>maven2</id>
          <url>http://n7701-sys274:8081/artifactory/maven2/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>maven-external</id>
          <url>http://n7701-sys274:8081/artifactory/maven-external</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>maven-public</id>
          <url>http://n7701-sys274:8081/artifactory/maven-public</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас Maven пытается обратиться к глобальному (central) репозиторию Maven: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, потому что любой pom.xml унаследован от т.н. super POM (http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.2/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html), в котором этот репозиторий задан.
Чтобы "сказать" Maven'у не использовать глобальный репозиторий, можно его переопределить в settings.xml и/или настроить ещё и mirror.
Подробности - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Repository#MavenRepository-ManuallyOverridingtheBuilt-inRepositories

Comment: спасибо,  но как оказалось проблема была в другой плоскости (я jirу не запустил ) и даже с тем же самым settings.xml прекрасно отработал